# Removed Core Location but still appears in settings

Tags: ios, core-location

I've just been given some legacy code in objective-c to remove location services from. I have removed all references to Core Location and the keys from the plist, but the app is still appearing in the location services settings. The confusing part is that the only option it displays is to 'never' allow the app access to the location. Once you click on this and go back, then 'Always' and 'When in use' then appear. Anyone got any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Most likely the permission appears from the earlier version of the app. Does the permission appear if the new app is installed on a new device (or simulator) that never had the old version?

Comment: That's what I initially thought as well, but it still comes up on brand new devices/simulators. It's really bizarre.

Comment: Is the CoreLocation framework still listed under "Link Binary With Libraries" on the Build Phases tab of your target?

Comment: Make sure Background Location isn't checked under the Background Modes capability.

Comment: Definitely hasn't got location updates checked under Background Modes, but funnily enough, it never had the CoreLocation framework listed under the 'Link Binary with Libraries' . Could this mean that its drawing CoreLocation from one of the other frameworks that have been imported, such as AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove Keys

```
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

From Plist And Remove `CoreLocation Framework` from Project.

Remove Location From Background Modes

Reinstall App.